# Having problems declaring SUMO_HOME

Tags: sumo

I'm trying to run a test python code to use the traci library and it is returning "please declare environment SUMO_HOME".

I'm on Ubuntu 18.4.2 and Sumo 0.32.0.I solved this problem before by running 
    `export SUMO_HOME=/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/tools/`
,but this time it couldn't solve the problem. So I tried implementing a line inside the python file using the os library giving the same command but from the code itself:
    `os.system("export SUMO_HOME=/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/tool/")`
And it also didn't work, so came here to ask for help. May any of you help me, please?

```
import os
import sys
import optparse

os.system("export SUMO_HOME=/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/tool/")
# we need to import some python modules from the $SUMO_HOME/tools directory
if 'SUMO_HOME' in os.environ:
    tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME=/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/tools/'], 'tools')
    sys.path.append(tools)
else:
    sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME'")


from sumolib import checkBinary  # Checks for the binary in environ vars
import traci


def get_options():
    opt_parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    opt_parser.add_option("--nogui", action="store_true",
                         default=False, help="run the commandline version of sumo")
    options, args = opt_parser.parse_args()
    return options


# contains TraCI control loop
def run():
    step = 0
    while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
        traci.simulationStep()
        print(step)
        step += 1

    traci.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()


# main entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = get_options()

    # check binary
    if options.nogui:
        sumoBinary = checkBinary('sumo')
    else:
        sumoBinary = checkBinary('sumo-gui')

    # traci starts sumo as a subprocess and then this script connects and runs
    traci.start([sumoBinary, "-c", "demo.sumocfg",
                             "--tripinfo-output", "tripinfo.xml"])
    run()
```

I expected for the steps to appear on the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swapped the if else part for another code :

```
try:
    sys.path.append("/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0/tools")
    from sumolib import checkBinary
except ImportError:
    sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME' as the root directory of your sumo installation (it should contain folders 'bin', 'tools' and 'docs')")
```

It solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

The correct location is probably

```
export SUMO_HOME=/home/gustavo/Downloads/sumo-0.32.0
```

without the tools or tool suffix. It will not work from inside the python script with os.system but you could modify os.environ directly.
Furthermore you mixed up the call to os.environ in the script. It should read:

```
tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME'], 'tools')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I tried modifying what you said and had the same problem.